# How to make a list of the indexes of capital letters in a word

Tags: list, indexing

I'm trying to solve a challenge that I found online. It gives an input word and the expected output is a list of the indexes of all the capital letters. My program works unless there's duplicate capital letters. I can't figure out how to deal with it. Here's my code right now:

```
def capital_indexes(string):
    string = list(string)
    print(string)
    output = []

    for i in string:
        if i.isupper():
            output.append(string. index(i))
    return output
```

Like I said, it works for words like "HeLlO" but not for words like "TesT"

Comment: Notice that `T` appears twice in the `word`, which causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and compare the difference with OP:

You don't have to use **index()** method to search the character again, just use **enumerate** to get the **tuple** of *(index, char)* at the same time, and check if the character is capital case.

```
def capital_indexes(string):
    #string = list(string)   # string is an iterable! 
    #print(string)
    output = []

    for i, ch in enumerate(string):    # get index, char 
        if ch.isupper():
            output.append(i)
    return output
    
print(capital_indexes('TesT')) # [0, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome. If this is helpful, can you ✅ and accept it?